# trouble with .toggle()

Tags: jquery

I have this CSS:

```
.linkMenu {
    width: 710px;
    height: 30px;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}
```

And this HTML:

```
<div id="linkAnchor0" class="linkMenu">
    text1
</div>

<div id="linkAnchor1" class="linkMenu" style="display:none;">
    text2
</div>
```

I'd like to know why `$("#linkAnchor1").show();` works (it shows the second div) and why `$("#linkAnchor1").toggle();` doesn't work (nothing is shown).

Where am I wrong?

---

**EDIT**

The whole jQuery code:

```
function showLinks(param) {
    if(param!="") {
        for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
            if(i<param) {
                $("#linkAnchor"+i).toggle();
            } else {
                $("#linkAnchor"+i).toggle();
                $("#linkAnchor"+i).find(".linkValue").children().val("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/HHLZq/

Comment: Theoretically, this should work... Are you sure there are no other variables in play here?

Comment: I've just tried your code and both .show() and .toggle() work fine? Do you have some CSS elsewhere in the site with `display: none !important` set on the element? Have you re-used the same id more than once?

Comment: Where is your complete jquery code?

Comment: Added the whole jQuery code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i'm getting this right, you're trying to do this:

```
function showLinks(param) {
  $(".linkMenu").toggle();
  $(".linkMenu:gt("+param+")").find(".linkValue").children().val("");
}
```